# View of attached files to a node

Tags: views, 8, files

I use D8 Editor File upload to add files to a node. But i want an overall view from all the files in that node, but only in that node. I can create a view for all the files but i can't filter on the nid of the current page.

The project: attachment_links seems to kinda do what i want but its only for Drupal 7.  Does anyone know of a similar Drupal 8 project or a way do code it manually into a block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [D8 Editor File upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_file) is using the Drupal file system, so the files uploaded through module do have FID and can be listed in Views.

Here are steps to create a block to show only the files used on the currently visited node:

1. Create a View of type `File` with a Block display showing Filename (you probably have this already)
2. Add a Contextual filter in your Views Block Display called **Entity ID** from the `File Usage` Category.
3. Adjust the settings for that Contextual filter:
   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Provide default value**
   `Type` to **Content ID from URL**
   `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`:
    **Specify validation criteria**
    `Validator` to **Content**
    `Content type` [choose appropriately]
    Leave the rest as default
4. Place the Block in a region you like, adjust the Block options `File Usage: Entity ID` to **Node from URL** and restrict to display only on relevant Content types.

Now when you visit nodes of the types you selected in Block and Contextual filter settings will list only the files uploaded to those nodes.

Comment: Awesome this work exactly like i wanted, thanks a lot.

Comment: I also work with paragraphs in the nodes i want to show files, but the files i put in paragraphs don't show up. I repeated the steps but with paragraph as the validator. This does not work. Is there a way to make it work with Paragraphs?

Comment: When i try to configure the 'file usage: entity id' in the  paragraph view block. My only option is -None-

Comment: I fixed the paragraph problem by making a custom block and then loading file ids and paragraph ids. But i just noticed i can't remove the files uploaded with d8 editor file uplload. so i have a big problem.

Comment: Paragraphs complicate things a bit and if you need more help try posting a new question with all the relevant information. About the d8 editor files: why are you using that module? If you wanted structured list of files used on a node using File field would give you that automatically. And if you delete the file from the field, it will no longer display on the list on that node. D8 editor file upload seems best suited for when you need a super simple file upload through the editor. For more complex needs File field would probably be better.